# Authenticate against PHP webservice using C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, authentication, soap

Here is the sample code for PHP Webservice client that works:

```
 $options = array();
 $options['trace'] = 1;   
 $options['login'] = 'username';
 $options['password'] = 'password';    
 $client = new SoapClient("http://wsurl.com/pt/wsdl", $options);
```

I would like to access this webservice using c# but having a hard time doing the authentication. Do I need to explicitly set the soap headers or there is a built in way to send credentials in .NET

Comment: The solution to this question does not apply to PHP. Re-tagging.

Comment: You probably need to use HTTP authentication. There is a built in way, but I don't remember exactly what is it (I'm not a .NET guy).

Comment: How are you calling the client? Did you "Add web service reference" to your project or are you playing with the lower level classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this because servers handle authentication differently. First you could use something like this:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create(<your url>);
NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(<username>, <password>);
req.Credentials = creds;

var rep = req.GetResponse();
```

However if you need an actual Authroization header you will want to use [this code](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Forcing-basic-http-authentication-for-HttpWebReq.html)

```
public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest req, String userName, String userPassword)
{
 string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
 authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
 req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
}
```

And then your request code becomes

```
var req = WebRequest.Create(<your url>);
SetBasicAuthHeader(req, username, password);
rep = req.GetResponse();
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a service reference in your C# project, you can just call your service like this:

```
var proxy = new YourServiceClient();
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

More information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx.